# Setup Geoserver Github code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, github, project, geoserver

I have downloaded the github source code and followed this link
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/quickstart/index.html#build-with-maven

The project build successfully, but when i try to import the project into Eclipse then it gives the error (a red cross on each of its project) but at the same time it runs without any problem by using (mvn jetty:run) command.

I want to import that code into my Eclipse without any errors. Can anyone help me out in successfully import the project into eclipse as mentioned in this link
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/developer/quickstart/eclipse.html
(Followed all the steps of the above mentioned link but cant able to run the code due to errors)

Comment: what errors do you see, if you hover your mouse over them? do a "mvn install" to get all packages from maven dependency list the project has... This should be available in project explorer in side before you run application

Comment: @Pravan Kate I see the errors in import statements, then i see errors in function calls as the called function isn't available in the respective class.

Comment: Did you try right-click and _Maven > Update Project..._?

Comment: yes i have tried it...At first try it build successfully using mvn clean install command but doesn't import into eclipse without errors. Now it is giving this error

ERROR] Failed to execute goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.1.15:revision (default) on project gs-wms: The plugin pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.1.15 requires Maven version [3.1.1,) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: Upgrade mvn version as the error suggests

Comment: @PavanKate How to do that in eclipse?

Comment: It looks like you are using an outdated Eclipse version: the version of Maven that is embedded in Eclipse Photon (4.8.0) is 3.5.3 (see _Window > Preferences: Maven > Installations_).